# AngularJS Form for text field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not able to validate the **AngularJS** form elements,
i have included the code snippet,  where as and when a key is pressed, the **"`onkeyup`**" event is triggered in order to call a java Script function which checks for the possible names.

And when i tried to put some validation to this field, I don't seem to have any effect applied.
     Kindly help me out with some suggestions.

```
<form name="findCusFrm">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input style=" width: 100%;"name="firstname"  onkeyup="fname();"class="textox form-control" id="firstname" type="text" 
             placeholder="Firstname" ng-pattern="/^[^\d][a-z A-Z]+$/" ng-minlength=3 ng-maxlength=20  ng-trim="true" required >
        <span ng-show="findCusFrm.firstname.$error.required && findCusFrm.firstname.$touched">First Name Required..     
        </span>
        <span ng-show="findCusFrm.firstname.$error.pattern && findCusFrm.firstname.$dirty">Invalid Field Format..                   
        </span>
       <span  ng-show="findCusFrm.firstname.$dirty && findCusFrm.firstname.$error.minlength">Too Short..
       </span>
       <span  ng-show="findCusFrm.firstname.$dirty && findCusFrm.firstname.$error.maxlength">Too Long..
       </span>
       <input type="hidden" id="setfname">
   </div>
```

And this is the fname() javascript function..

```
function fname()
{

 $(document).ready(function(){
     var autocomplete;
                      $("#firstname").autocomplete({
                          source: "requestfname.html",
                          minLength: 1,
                          response: function (event, ui) {
                              if ((ui['content'].length) == 0) {
                                alert("No such fname Exists!!!");
                              }
                          },
                          select: function (event, ui) {
                             $('#email').val(ui.item.value);
                              var element = document.getElementById('setfname');
                              element.value = ui.item.value;
                           // alert(element.value); 

                          }
                      });
    });
```

}

Comment: Try using `ng-keyup=""` for a start, can we see your function `fname`. Also, you need to bind the input to a `$scope` property (`ng-model` attribute).

Comment: step 1 get rid of the onkeyup and use a directive ng-keyup for instance.

Comment: Thank you Stem,
i have included the fname() to question..  And  are suggesting that to write the fname() within the angularJS controller or will it just work fine if i just replace "onkeyup" with " ng-keyup" ???

Comment: In angularJs you should never use  $(document).ready(function() ... its almost useless. Instead of that you should write or use existing one directive https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **ng-keyup** instead of **onclick()** and completely avoiding the **jQuery** code helped me to get the solution i needed